# Performing UPDATE with AFTER UPDATE trigger SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I have a table with 1000+ records in SQL Server 2008 R2. There is a SharePoint 2010 interface where users can update the rows of this table in real time, and there is one field (CLASS) that should be calculated upon update of one or two columns (COUNTRY_REASON or/and VENDOR_REASON).

I am thinking about creating an AFTER UPDATE trigger upon update, although I wonder if it won't get in a loop of some kind?

Is there a better way to perform this update than using a trigger? What is your opinion/advice?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_NOSSCE_UPDATE_CLASS] 
ON [TO_BDB].[dbo].[to_bdb_nossce_comm_act] 
after UPDATE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE [TO_BDB].[dbo].[to_bdb_nossce_comm_act] 
      SET    class = CASE 
                       WHEN ( country_reason = '' OR country_reason IS NULL ) 
                            AND ( vendor_reason = '' OR vendor_reason IS NULL ) 
                       THEN 'NOT CLASSIFIED' 
                       WHEN country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue' 
                            AND ( vendor_reason = '' OR vendor_reason IS NULL ) 
                       THEN 'SITE ISSUE' 
                       WHEN country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue' 
                             OR country_reason = '' 
                             OR country_reason IS NULL 
                      THEN ( 
                         CASE 
                           WHEN vendor_reason IN ( 'Site Product Quality', 'Site QA Release' ) 
                           THEN 'SITE QUALITY' 
                           WHEN vendor_reason = 'Customer Order Management' 
                           THEN 'CPO SCM' 
                         WHEN vendor_reason LIKE 'Other%' THEN 'OTHER REASON' 
                         ELSE 'SITE SCM' 
                         END 
                       ) 
                       ELSE ( 
                         CASE 
                                WHEN country_reason IN ( 'Local Product Quality', 
                                                         'Local QA Release' 
                                                       ) 
                                THEN 'CPO QUALITY' 
                                WHEN country_reason IN ( 'Customs Clearance', 
                                                         'Transport Damage', 
                                                         'Transport Issue' ) 
                                THEN 'TRANSIT' 
                                WHEN country_reason IN ( 
                                     'Artwork', 'Complaince Checks', 
                                     'Registration', 
                                     'Safety Label Changes' ) 
                                THEN 'CPO LCM' 
                                WHEN country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue' 
                                THEN '' 
                                WHEN country_reason LIKE 'Other%' 
                                THEN 'OTHER REASON' 
                                ELSE 'CPO SCM' 
                          END 
                        ) 
                     END 
      WHERE  class = '' 
              OR class IS NULL 
                 AND Len(comment) > 0 
  END 

go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `"INSTEAD OF INSERT,UPDATE"` and avoid the update with a single insert

Articles:

- [Using INSTEAD OF Triggers - MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [How to Use INSTEAD OF Trigger - Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/24/sql-server-how-to-use-instead-of-trigger-guest-post-by-vikas-munjal-koenig-solutions/)

Try this ! add other columns where i have commented

```
create  TRIGGER TRG_NOSSCE_UPDATE_CLASS
ON [dbo].[to_bdb_nossce_comm_act]
instead OF UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      UPDATE a
      SET    a.class = CASE
                         WHEN ( a.country_reason = ''
                                 OR a.country_reason IS NULL )
                              AND ( a.vendor_reason = ''
                                     OR a.vendor_reason IS NULL ) THEN 'NOT CLASSIFIED'
                         WHEN a.country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue'
                              AND ( a.vendor_reason = ''
                                     OR a.vendor_reason IS NULL ) THEN 'SITE ISSUE'
                         WHEN a.country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue'
                               OR a.country_reason = ''
                               OR a.country_reason IS NULL THEN ( CASE
                                                                  WHEN a.vendor_reason IN ( 'Site Product Quality', 'Site QA Release' ) THEN 'SITE QUALITY'
                                                                  WHEN a.vendor_reason = 'Customer Order Management' THEN 'CPO SCM'
                                                                  WHEN a.vendor_reason LIKE 'Other%' THEN 'OTHER REASON'
                                                                  ELSE 'SITE SCM'
                                                                END )
                         ELSE ( CASE
                                  WHEN a.country_reason IN ( 'Local Product Quality', 'Local QA Release' ) THEN 'CPO QUALITY'
                                  WHEN a.country_reason IN ( 'Customs Clearance', 'Transport Damage', 'Transport Issue' ) THEN 'TRANSIT'
                                  WHEN a.country_reason IN ( 'Artwork', 'Complaince Checks', 'Registration', 'Safety Label Changes' ) THEN 'CPO LCM'
                                  WHEN a.country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue' THEN ''
                                  WHEN a.country_reason LIKE 'Other%' THEN 'OTHER REASON'
                                  ELSE 'CPO SCM'
                                END )
                       END
      --,
      --a.column1=b.column1,
      --a.othercolumns=b.othercolumns
      FROM   [dbo].[to_bdb_nossce_comm_act] a,
             inserted b
      WHERE  a.class = ''
              OR a.class IS NULL
                 AND Len(a.comment) > 0
  END

go
```

Imagining you use a cursor in your SP and have @class,@countryreason and @vendorreason as cursor variables, we can do as below

```
cursor loop....start
SET   @class = CASE
                         WHEN ( @country_reason = ''
                                 OR @country_reason IS NULL )
                              AND ( vendor_reason = ''
                                     OR @vendor_reason IS NULL ) THEN 'NOT CLASSIFIED'
                         WHEN @country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue'
                              AND ( @vendor_reason = ''
                                     OR @vendor_reason IS NULL ) THEN 'SITE ISSUE'
                         WHEN @country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue'
                               OR @country_reason = ''
                               OR @country_reason IS NULL THEN ( CASE
                                                                  WHEN @vendor_reason IN ( 'Site Product Quality', 'Site QA Release' ) THEN 'SITE QUALITY'
                                                                  WHEN @vendor_reason = 'Customer Order Management' THEN 'CPO SCM'
                                                                  WHEN @vendor_reason LIKE 'Other%' THEN 'OTHER REASON'
                                                                  ELSE 'SITE SCM'
                                                                END )
                         ELSE ( CASE
                                  WHEN @country_reason IN ( 'Local Product Quality', 'Local QA Release' ) THEN 'CPO QUALITY'
                                  WHEN @country_reason IN ( 'Customs Clearance', 'Transport Damage', 'Transport Issue' ) THEN 'TRANSIT'
                                  WHEN @country_reason IN ( 'Artwork', 'Complaince Checks', 'Registration', 'Safety Label Changes' ) THEN 'CPO LCM'
                                  WHEN @country_reason = 'Vendor_Issue' THEN ''
                                  WHEN @country_reason LIKE 'Other%' THEN 'OTHER REASON'
                                  ELSE 'CPO SCM'
                                END )
                       END

update table set other columns....,class=@class,.... where...

close cursor loop
```

SP can be more clear only if u share a piece or glance of it.

Comment: Hello Anand, thanks! Can you explain why is this solution is good for this case? I read a few articles about INSTEAD OF triggers, and they almost always relate it to views. I have an approx. 1000 rows table, and SharePoint will perform an update when the user updates the row. I want the trigger to update a column, depending on the values that the user chose (and these values come in with the update).

Comment: Our goal is to update the field 'class'.Based on what reason the user has entered that row should be updated using case. So instead of letting first update happen followed by second for the same record, we stop and make change in the incoming record and do as a single update.

Comment: Instead of triggers are attached to a table in a similar way, but the code inside them is executed in place of the original updating statement. www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1437741/Simplifying-Instead-Of-Triggers.htm

Comment: OK the fog is getting thinner :) ! So the "inserted b" will be a virtual table where the update is about to take place, in this case  identical to the original table (table a), and I need to join all columns where you commented --a.column1=b.column1 etc. etc.?

Comment: refer this technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435(v=sql.80).aspx and yes join columns you use to identify unique combination if there is any

Comment: I couldn't get this tested today because I need the SP guy... as soon as it's tested I let you know!

Comment: if you are to use SP you can put this logic inside that and avoid the trigger all together. that can be super efficient.I will try to update my answer for an SP

Comment: I woudl not put this in an sp if it needs to run no matter how the records are updated. What if someone decides to start using an ORM istead of the SP in one place in the application? Wht is some oprocess outside teh application affect the table like an data import or an ad hoc query to fix some bad data? A trigger is the best route here.

Comment: @HLGEM : I agree with you.i saw the word 'better' from performance side and thought of avoiding these trigger bots. :)